# How can I adjust code to work with two parameters instead of one?

Tags: java, parameters, tostring

I need help with this project. I cannot seem to find a way to get the test code to run. I am not allowed to change the test code, only the IntegerSet class. I am still learning, please help me in figuring this out.

I know the codes are long so I placed the comments PROBLEM! near the two spots in the test and current code where there seems to be a red flag.
Maybe toString() has to do with it but not sure.

Current code:

```
  public class IntegerSet {
  private int [] a;  // holds a set of numbers from 0 - 100

  public IntegerSet () {
    // an empty set, all a[i] are set to 0
    a = new int [101];
  }

  // A constructor that copies from an existing set.
  public IntegerSet (IntegerSet existingSet) {
    a = new int [101];
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
      a[i] = existingSet.a[i];
  }

  public void deleteElement(int i) {
    if ((i >= 0) && (i < a.length))
      a[i] = 0;  // set to 1
  }

  public void insertElement(int i) {
    if ((i >= 0) && (i < a.length))
      a[i] = 1;  // set to 1
  }

  public boolean isSet(int i) {
    return (a[i] == 1);
  }
  // PROBLEM!!!!

  // The union of this set and another set
  public IntegerSet union(IntegerSet otherSet) {
    IntegerSet newSet = new IntegerSet(this);

    // newSet is now a copy of the current set,  Next we
    // want to union with set a

    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
      if (otherSet.isSet(i))
        newSet.insertElement(i);
    }

    return newSet;
  }
  // PROBLEM!!!
  // The intersection of this set and another set
  public IntegerSet intersection(IntegerSet otherSet) {
    IntegerSet newSet = new IntegerSet(this);

    // newSet is now a copy of the current set,  Next we
    // want to intersect with set a

    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
      if (!otherSet.isSet(i))
        newSet.deleteElement(i);
    }

    return newSet;
  }


  // return true if the set has no elements
  public boolean isEmpty() {
    for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
      if (isSet(i)) return false;
    return true;
  }

  // return the 'length' of a set
  public int cardinality() {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
      if (isSet(i))
        count++;
    return count;
  }

  // Print a set to System.out
  public void setPrint() {
    System.out.print("[Set:");

    if (isEmpty())
      System.out.print("---");

    for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
      if (isSet(i))
        System.out.print(" " + i);
    }

    System.out.print("]\n");
  }

  // return true if two sets are equal
  public boolean isEqualTo(IntegerSet otherSet) {
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
      if (otherSet.isSet(i) != isSet(i))
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Test Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IntegerSetTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        IntegerSet setA = new IntegerSet();
        IntegerSet setB = new IntegerSet();

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input;

        do {            
            // Just for formatting purposes...
            System.out.println();            
            System.out.println("setA: " + setA);
            System.out.println("setB: " + setB);
            System.out.println("1) insertElement into setA");
            System.out.println("2) deleteElement from setA");
            System.out.println("3) insertElement into setB");
            System.out.println("4) deleteElement from setB");
            System.out.println("5) intersection of setA and setB");
            System.out.println("6) union of setA and setB");
            System.out.println("7) equality of setA and setB");
            System.out.println("Select from the menu above (or 0 to exit): ");
            input = scan.nextInt();

            switch(input) {
                case 1: 
                    System.out.print("Enter an element to insert into setA: ");
                    setA.insertElement(scan.nextInt());
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.print("Enter an element to delete from setA: ");
                    setA.deleteElement(scan.nextInt());                  
                    break;
                case 3:    
                    System.out.print("Enter an element to insert into setB: ");
                    setB.insertElement(scan.nextInt());                 
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.print("Enter an element to delete from setB: ");
                    setB.deleteElement(scan.nextInt());                  
                    break;
                case 5: // PROBLEM!   
                    System.out.println("The intersection of setA and setB is: " + IntegerSet.intersection(setA, setB));
                    break;
                case 6: // PROBLEM!
                    System.out.println("The union of setA and setB is: " + IntegerSet.union(setA, setB));
                    break;
                case 7:
                    System.out.println("setA and setB are " + (setA.isEqualTo(setB) ? "" : "un") + "equal");
                    break;
                default:
                    if (input != 0) {
                        System.out.println("\n*** Error, invalid input! ***\n");
                    }
            }          
        }while(input != 0);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public static IntegerSet union(IntegerSet otherSet, IntegerSet nextSet) {

    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
      if (otherSet.isSet(i))
        nextSet.insertElement(i);
    }

    return nextSet;
  }

  public static IntegerSet intersection(IntegerSet otherSet, IntegerSet nextSet) {

    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
      if (!otherSet.isSet(i))
        nextSet.deleteElement(i);
    }

    return nextSet;
  }
```

Comment: I can't edit the test, like what you did. I can change the current code. Just not sure how to add the two arguments.

Comment: I have changed my answer please check now

Comment: because a is private, a.length does not work properly. I changed it to static but that makes the program worse

Comment: you cannot use a use the length of the passed parameters. Add a method length() in IntegerSet to get the length of the objects

Comment: like this? public int length() {
      int count = 0;
      for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
        if (isSet(i))
          count++;
      return count;
    }

Answer (score 0):

You'll notice that the test code is running

```
IntegerSet.intersection(setA, setB)
IntegerSet.union(setA, setB)
```

as opposed to

```
setA.intersection(setB)
setA.union(setB)
```

The difference is that the first are calls to static methods, and the second are calls to instance methods.  Your implementation contains instance methods, which use themselves (`this`) instead of accepting a second parameter.

(In short, change `this` to the value of a second parameter and add the `static` keyword to your method.  Also, you'll have to change the reference to the private `a` to use the accessor methods.)

Comment: What if I just remove the private?

Comment: How can I change the reference?